# MySQL query PHP/PDO with JSON encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I know the query I need works, but I can't seem to execute it in a way that works via PHP with a PDO execute.

In short I have a table called type:

```
+-------------++----------------+
|   type_id   ||   type_name    |
+-------------++----------------+
      1               Car
      2               Bus
      3               Lorry
```

And a table called asset_details:

```
+-------------++----------------+
|   type_id   ||     cost       |
+-------------++----------------+
      1              10
      1              10
      1              20
      2              300
      3              600
      3              800
      1              70
```

I want to output as JSON enconde so that I can sum all the type_ids from asset_details. ie, above we have 4 cars, 2 lorries, 1 bus. I only need the value so I've tried

```
$json = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM asset_details GROUP BY type_id')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

echo json_encode($json);
```

But that gives me an echo of:

```
{"4":[],"2":[],"1":[]}
```

I need it to be:

```
["7" , "3"]
```

so that I can use that for data within chartJS. I'm sure it's the fetch method, but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: You should try to group by type_id and do not calculate count using php

Comment: Try PDO::FETCH_COLUMN instead of PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE for your flags in the fetchAll method.